# confusing about nested for loop in order to increase multiple index

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question is asking to create a nested loop to append and increase multiple index in a 2D list,for somehow I can't print the element in the list and i tried to print the length of the list it just return 0.

the expect value in the list is:

If duration of the music sequence is 1s, starting pitch is 60 and ending pitch is 64, then the content of the music list for one sequence will be:

```
[ [0.0, 60, 0.2],
  [0.2, 61, 0.2],
  [0.4, 62, 0.2],
  [0.6, 63, 0.2],
  [0.8, 64, 0.2] ]
```

There are 5 music notes because the pitch number starts from 60 and goes up to 64, i.e. number of notes = 64 - 60 + 1

The duration of each music note is 0.2s, which is just the duration of the music sequence divided by 5

so the list is

```py
music_data=[time,pitch,duration]
```

here are more examples
if the music sequence is repeated twice, an example music data with five notes (from 60 to 64 and a music sequence duration of 1 second) will look like this:

```
[ [0.0, 60, 0.2],
  [0.2, 61, 0.2],
  [0.4, 62, 0.2],
  [0.6, 63, 0.2],
  [0.8, 64, 0.2],
  [1.0, 60, 0.2],
  [1.2, 61, 0.2],
  [1.4, 62, 0.2],
  [1.6, 63, 0.2],
  [1.8, 64, 0.2] ]
```

You need to be careful that the range of pitch numbers works quite differently for increasing pitch numbers (step = 1) and decreasing pitch numbers (step = -1)
You also need to make sure that the range of pitch numbers is inclusive of the starting pitch and the ending pitch values

For example, if the starting pitch and ending pitch are 60 and 72 respectively, you will need write range(60, 73) to generate the correct range of pitch numbers

The function template provided by task:

```py
# This function makes a piece of crazy music in the music list
def makeCrazyMusic():
    global music_data

    #####
    #
    # TODO:
    # - Ask for the crazy music parameters
    # - Clear the music list
    # - Use a nested loop to generate the crazy music in the music list
    # - Update the music summary
    #
    #####
```

After refer to the instruction, i ve tried :

```py
def makeCrazyMusic():
    global music_data

    #####
    #
    # TODO:
    # - Ask for the crazy music parameters
    # - Clear the music list
    # - Use a nested loop to generate the crazy music in the music list
    # - Update the music summary
    #
    #####

    #time = start time of note
    #pitch the pitch of note
    #durantion the length of the note

    #duration = duration / note --constant
    #         = duration / startpitch -endpitch+1)
    #note = start pitch - end pitch +1
    #time = time + duration
    #pitch = from start to end
    #
    try:
        times_input = int(turtle.numinput("Times to play",\
                                        "Please enter number of times to play the sequence:"))
        dura_input = float(turtle.numinput("Duration",\
                                        "Please enter duration to play the sequence:"))
        start_pitch = int(turtle.numinput("Start pitch",\
                                        "Please enter Start pitch to play the sequence:"))
        end_pitch = int(turtle.numinput("End Pitch",\
                                        "Please enter end pitch of the sequence:"))
    except TypeError:
        return
    
    music_data=[] #[time(+duration),pitch(nonc),duration(const)]
    index=0
    for index in range(times_input):
        for pitch in (start_pitch,end_pitch+1):
            music_data.append([index,start_pitch,dura_input/times_input])
            index= index+(dura_input/times_input)
            start_pitch= start_pitch+1
    for x in range(len(music_data)):
        print(music_data[x])
```

The expected OUTPUT is:
if the music sequence is repeated twice, an example music data with five notes (from 60 to 64 and a music sequence duration of 1 second) will look like this:

```py
#times_input =2
#dura_input = 1
#start_pitch =60
#end_pitch =64
[ [0.0, 60, 0.2],
  [0.2, 61, 0.2],
  [0.4, 62, 0.2],
  [0.6, 63, 0.2],
  [0.8, 64, 0.2],
  [1.0, 60, 0.2],
  [1.2, 61, 0.2],
  [1.4, 62, 0.2],
  [1.6, 63, 0.2],
  [1.8, 64, 0.2] ]
```

The ACTUAL OUTPUT:

```py
[0, 60, 0.5]
[0.5, 61, 0.5]
[1, 62, 0.5]
[1.5, 63, 0.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the duration of each note by dividing the total duration by the number of notes. Then use this in a list comprehension.

```
def pitches_list(start, end, total_duration):
    duration = total_duration / (end - start + 1)
    return [[i * duration, start + i, duration] for i in range(end - start + 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please take a look at my add-on, still confused

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved issue, here is the code:

```py
def makeCrazyMusic():
    global music_data

    #####
    #
    # TODO:
    # - Ask for the crazy music parameters
    # - Clear the music list
    # - Use a nested loop to generate the crazy music in the music list
    # - Update the music summary
    #
    #####

  
    try:
        times_input = int(turtle.numinput("Times to play",\
                                        "Please enter number of times to play the sequence:"))
        dura_input = float(turtle.numinput("Duration",\
                                        "Please enter duration to play the sequence:"))
        start_pitch = int(turtle.numinput("Start pitch",\
                                        "Please enter Start pitch to play the sequence:"))
        end_pitch = int(turtle.numinput("End Pitch",\
                                        "Please enter end pitch of the sequence:"))
    except TypeError:
        return
    
    music_data=[] #[time(+duration),pitch(nonc),duration(const)]
    index=0
    duration = dura_input/(start_pitch - end_pitch+1)
    duration2 =dura_input/(end_pitch - start_pitch+1)
    for index in range(times_input):
        if start_pitch > end_pitch:
            for pitch in range(start_pitch,end_pitch-1,-1):
                music_data.append([index,pitch,duration])
                index= index+duration
                #start_pitch= start_pitch+1
        if start_pitch<end_pitch:
            for pitch in range(start_pitch,end_pitch+1,1):
                music_data.append([index,pitch,duration2])
                index= index+duration2
   # for x in range(len(music_data)):
    #    print(music_data[x])
    updateMusicSummary()
```